# Scheme: advise on implementation of flatten

Tags: list, functional-programming, scheme, flatten

My implementation of `flatten` looks like this:

```
(define flatten
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        lst
        (append
          (rtn-lst (car lst))
          (flatten (cdr lst))))))

(define rtn-lst
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond 
      ((null? lst) 
        empty)
      ((atom? lst)
        (list lst))
      (else 
        (flatten lst)))))
```

While standard implementation is:

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (cond 
    ((null? list)
      empty)
    ((list? (car lst))
      (append (flatten (car lst)) (flatten (cdr lst))))
    (else
      (cons (car lst) (flatten (cdr lst))))))
```

Apart from the obvious verboseness, what else is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
(define rtn-lst
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond 
      ((list? lst)
        (if (null? lst)
            empty
            (flatten-list lst)))
      ((atom? lst)
        (list lst))
      (else 
        (flatten-list lst)))))
```

Probably we have different implementations of Scheme.

**EDIT:**

With modified `else` branch:

```
(define rtn-lst
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond 
      ((list? lst)
        (if (null? lst)
            empty
            (flatten-list lst)))
      (else 
        (list lst)))))
```

Comment: @Yasir My version works correctly with (list 1 2 3 4) and returns '(1 2 3 4) so your reasoning is missing something.

Comment: R5RS: library procedure: null? obj
Returns #t if obj is the empty list, otherwise returns #f. So you can call `null?` with every datatype.

Comment: @Yasir: that is interesting. Which scheme implementation you are using? I am using DrRacket with Language pack set to  "Essentials of Programming Languages (3rd ed.)" . Sorry for being too curious. I am new to Scheme and functional programming so getting to know best practices and good style is a goal.

Comment: @sudhirc: I'm using Racket, too, but I have `#lang racket` in my source, and I'm using `symbol?` instead of `atom?`.

Comment: @Yasir: Thanks I can see the behaviour when language is set to racket. But strangely your procedure also fails to return anything when I set #lang racket. Are various scheme implementations so different(read incompatible) ?

Comment: @sudhirc: You're quite welcome. Ensure you've set "Determine language from source" option in the bottom of the DrRacket window. `(flatten-list (list 'a (list 'b (list 'c 'd 1 2)) 'e 'f))` returns `'(a b c d 1 2 e f)` for me.

Comment: @Yasir: I see the result now. thanks a ton. Do you suggest sticking to racket language instead of "Essentials of Programming Languages (3rd ed.)" ? I believe racket is most recent language.

Comment: @sudhirc: I think it doesn't really matter what language are you using. But, I would have as little functions provided by you interpreter as possible in the beginning of your education, because it's better to implement things yourself to understand how they're working. Implement `foldl`, `map`, `reverse`, `append`, `apply` whatsoever; this is funny and useful. Also, you don't need to put @ in front of the nick of the user whose post you're commenting, I would be noted of the comment by the system anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider `atom?` to be wrong. You want to know if the `lst` is a list, so use `list?`. `atom?` can return false on `vector` or `string` for some implementations. But i do not know for sure. The rest is quit good.

Comment: that looks like a good catch. Other than that what do you think about overall style?

Comment: Style is very subjective ... but I would use less lines for `cond` in `rtn-lst`, like `(cond ((null? lst) empty) ; nextline`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
(define foo
  (lambda (e)
    (cond ((pair? e) `(,@(foo (car e)) ,@(foo (cdr e))))
          ((null? e) '())
          (else (list e)))))
```

Where for example:

```
> (foo '(((2 3) (4 . 5) 8)))
(2 3 4 5 8)
```

Does this do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
(define (flatten x y)
    (if (null? x)
        y
        (if (list? (car x))
            (flatten (append (car x) (cdr x)) y)
            (flatten (cdr x) (append y (list (car x)))))))
(define (flat x)     
    (flatten x '()))

> (flat '(1(2(3(4(5)6)7)8)9))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

and closure version:

```
(define (flatten x)  
        (define (flatten x y)
            (if (null? x)
                y
                (if (list? (car x))
                    (flatten (append (car x) (cdr x)) y)
                    (flatten (cdr x) (append y (list (car x)))))))
        (flatten x '()))

> (flatten '(1(2(3(4(5)6)7)8)9))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: repeatedly appending singleton list to the end of list (with `(append y (list (car x))))` is bound to have *quadratic* time behavior.  your `flatten`'s list restructuring is reminiscent of the classic [`gopher`](https://dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html), should be basis to the overall linear solution. don't fight the recursion; if making the code *tail* recursive causes it to become quadratic, then clearly this is not desired.